# XSLT with test and otherwise

Tags: xml, if-statement, xslt

I have below xslt where ID and LASTNAME are the input parameters. When ID matches the EMPLOYEE_ID in the VW_JAX_EMP_JOB_DEPTRECORDSELECT then set the Last_Name element as s0:PREFERREDLASTNAME otherwise se the input parameter LASTNAME. Below one doesnt work.

```
 <xsl:template name="GetLastNameVW_JAX_EMP_JOB_DEPT"> 
   <xsl:param name="ID" />
   <xsl:param name = "LASTNAME" />
   <xsl:element name="Last_Name">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="//s0:VW_JAX_EMP_JOB_DEPTRECORDSELECT[s0:EMPLOYEE_ID = $ID]/s0:PREFERREDLASTNAME">
         <xsl:value-of select="//s0:VW_JAX_EMP_JOB_DEPTRECORDSELECT[s0:EMPLOYEE_ID = $ID]/s0:PREFERREDLASTNAME" />
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise> LASTNAME
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:element> 
 </xsl:template>
```

Can anyone please suggest me ho to set the otherwise tag here.

Comment: In `<xsl:otherwise>`, it should be `$LASTNAME`. `$` is missing if that is the expected value in the output.

Answer (score 1):

If I don't missunderstand your intentions I beliveve you are looking for

```
<xsl:value-of select="$LASTNAME"/>
```

Or if the lastname is more complex

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$LASTNAME"/>
```

See [W3school Value of](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_value_of.asp) and [W3School Copy of](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ref_xsl_el_copy-of.asp)